# Crazy 403 Forbidden Error on Wordpress Site

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, http-status-code-403

Just installed a new theme on my site: www.rivertam.co

For some reason I keep getting this 403 Forbidden error at the top of it.

I've tried removing the htaccess file like some have suggested, nothing happens. Really no idea why it's there.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Happy to paste any PHP you may need. Just let me know!

Header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

> 
> 
> 
>

```
<title><?php wp_title( ' ', true, 'right' ); /* filtered in libraries/filers.php */ ?></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.gif" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/apple-touch-icon.png" />

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<?php
    // See functions.php for CSS / JAVASCRIPT information
    wp_head(); // do not remove this        
?>
```

>

```
<div id="branding_wrap">
    <header id="branding">  
        <div class="container">

            <?php
                // Grab the column settings from theme settings to determine the logo/menu container sizes
                $logo_columns = $menu_columns = "eight";
                $header_layout = cudazi_get_option( 'header_layout', 'eight|eight' );
                $header_layout = explode('|', $header_layout);
                if ( is_array( $header_layout ) ) {
                    $logo_columns = $header_layout[0];
                    $menu_columns = $header_layout[1];
                }                   
            ?>

            <hgroup class="<?php echo $logo_columns; ?> columns">               
                <h1 id="logo"><?php echo cudazi_get_logo(); ?></h1>
                <?php if ( ! cudazi_get_option( 'disable_tagline', false ) ) { ?>
                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
                <?php } ?>
            </hgroup>       
            <nav class="<?php echo $menu_columns; ?> columns" id="navigation" role="navigation">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu clearfix', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => 'cudazi_menu_fallback' ) ); ?>                        
                <?php echo cudazi_alternate_menu( array( 'menu_name' => 'primary', 'display' => 'select' ) ); ?>
            </nav>
        </div><!--//container (skeleton) -->
    </header><!--//header-->
</div>

<section id="main">
```

Comment: Search `403 Forbidden` in your theme,as site seems to be working fine except that text.

Comment: Something is causing the server's 403 Forbidden page code to be injected into the end of your header (just before the closing `</head>` tag) even though the site is accessible.  Can you post the code for your theme's `header.php` file?  I've never seen this kind of thing happen but possibly some resource called in the header is causing this.

Comment: Also, have you tried disabling plugins to see if one of those is responsible?

Comment: Hey Ennui,

I added the code at the top as best I could for you!

Comment: I disabled all plugins. Didn't help =[

Answer (score 0):

Do you include any other files programmativally? (AJAX?)
If yes I would first check permissions! Files have to be world-readable (in normal setups) to be delivered through web...